# yarn: export as normal ES6 module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg-v2

Take a trivial example like this:

```
const myFunc = () => console.log("foo");
export const funcs = {myFunc};
```

I want to be able to import this with the browser's `import()` function and be able to access `mod.funcs`.

If I import that source code directly in the browser, everything works. But, how do I get yarn to build a version which is still importable?

If I try to build that version, then the compiled version is just `(()=>{"use strict"})();` without the function at all.

I've also tried:

```
module.exports = {myFunc};
```

Which seems to produce some code which includes the function, but I'm still unable to access it after importing it in the browser.

Building with yarn, which is calling `react-scripts build`.

---

Full application I'm trying to build:

The application needs to be able to import an arbitrary user-defined JS module to provide customisation. Currently, this is done with:

```
    import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ js_module).then((mod) => {
        Object.assign(COMPONENTS, mod.components);
        Object.assign(USER_FUNCS, mod.funcs);
    });
```

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-admin/blob/master/admin-js/src/App.js#L77

This should work with vanilla JS modules (e.g. to do add simple functions that can be used for validators) without build tools. This currently works fine, for example this module loads without a problem, adding a new function to the application: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-admin/blob/master/examples/validators.py#L15-L21

It also needs to work with a React module so that custom react-admin components can be added to the components object. This is the part I'm struggling to build. If I build and export a component as a module, when I load it into the application I get errors from React's useContext(), which I presume is because the context in the user module is not the same context in the application.

For testing, I mostly copied the code for the CloneButton (and will modify it once something is actually working): https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/61555343ac1d325effc75f21591c422c7825e918/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/CloneButton.tsx
It's the useResourceContext(), useRecordContext() etc. that fail inside React's useContext().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full solution to my problems looks like this:

First, in the main application save a reference to the library we need somewhere accessible:

```
import React from 'react';
window.React = React;
```

---

Now in our module where we create some custom components, create shims for each library, such as:

```
// shim/react/index.js
module.exports = window.React;
```

Then in `package.json` we can update the dependencies and define resolutions, to both point to the shims:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "file:./shim/react",
},
"resolutions": {
  "react": "file:./shim/react",
}
```

This will cause all references to React to get passed through to the application's version of React, rather than compiling another version into the module. By using this shim for react-admin, we can ensure the components will all use the same context and work correctly. It also significantly reduces the file size of the module.

---

Finally, the module exporting custom components also needs to be built as an ES6 module. To achieve this without ejecting the project, we can use craco.

First, add craco to the dependencies and update the scripts:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
  ...
  "react": "file:./shim/react",
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "craco build",
  "test": "craco test",
  "eject": "craco eject"
},
```

Then add a `craco.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      output: {
        library: {
          type: 'module'
        }
      },
      experiments: {outputModule: true}
    }
  }
}
```

Then the project can be built normally with `yarn install` and `yarn build`.

Answer (score 1):

[Library mode](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library) is probably what you are searching for. Try adding those line to your webpack.config.js :

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    output: {
        // ...
        globalObject: 'this',
        library: {
          name: 'myLibrary',
          type: 'umd',
        },
    }
}
```

This will tell webpack to expose your exported functions. Change the library name to suit your needs.

Comment: That requires using `react-scripts eject`, right? Guessing there's no way to do it without that?

Comment: Based on the information you provided I tend to think it is the only solution in your case. If you are willing to add more concrete details about what you are trying to do maybe we could try and figure out a better solution;
Like what exactly are you exporting and why? How have you initialized your project? What are you making?

Comment: Well, this works for my original question (except type should be 'module'). What I'm trying to do is build react-admin components in a standalone module that can be imported dynamically into another project, but now realise that all the React useContext() stuff doesn't work, presumably because the context in the module is not the same context in the application. Code that imports it is: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-admin/blob/master/admin-js/src/App.js#L77

Comment: I'd also like that import logic to work with vanilla JS files (without build tools) (e.g. https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-admin/blob/master/examples/validators.py#L21), for loading functions etc., as well as compiled React modules (obviously needed when using custom components).

Comment: So the app that's in your `src` folder is the one you want to use somewhere else? You're also saying you would want to export the components, but then say you want to be able to use the result in a vanilla JS project... I'm not quite sure what you mean.
Also I've not seen any use of the `useContext` hook in your code. you were probably talking about the project from which you want to import.
Please update your question with as many details as possible - or open another topic and mark this as an answer if your problem has evolved !

Comment: Added a new section with details of the application. The latter link is a vanilla JS module that is dynamically imported into the main application in the first link (so the reverse of what you said). But, I want to also be able to use a React module in place of the vanilla JS module (so the user can choose either approach for customisation, though the React approach would obviously be needed if they want to add custom react-admin components).

Comment: To me it just seems like you need to provide a copy of your plain, non-built React components in order to reuse them. I'll read again your code and edits tomorrow and provide another answer with links and examples asap

Comment: craco allows changing the output to ES6 module without ejecting. I've included instructions for this in the last section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The environment of you project is a bit unusual at least to me, but with your updates and code samples I think what you're looking for definitely requires `react-scripts eject` anyways, because you will eventually need to customize your webpack and babel config.
You're probably aware, but it's worth reminding it's a one-time, non reversible action.

For the use as standalone vanilla JS module, maybe keep using the output config from my other answer that worked initially.

And for the React components, simply copying the component files in a subfolder of your `dist/` folder (or whatever output folder you have) as suggested should work. You could use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to achieve that.

I hope it gives you tracks to follow for an eventual solution. Don't hesitate if you have more webpack or JS-modules related questions, I'd be happy to help if I can.

Comment: I think there's still a little confusion on what I'm trying to do.
The first part (App.js), is already built and compiled, so when the user runs the Python application, the pre-compiled app will be loaded.

Comment: The second part, is a JS module that the user writes themselves and can export functions and components, which will then be automatically used in the application to customise the behaviour.

Comment: In the code I pointed to, I have demonstrated a vanilla JS module from the user (with no build tools) which exports a simple function. This works fine.
But, if the user wants to create a module with React components, I can't figure out how to do that. If I try to use any components after dynamically importing them from the user module, I just get null related errors inside of useContext() (e.g from calling useResourceContext() in the CloneButton). I'm pretty sure this is because the user components refer to a different context than the application due to them being compiled separately.

Comment: The user module is loaded in App.js by URL. So, App.js is never aware of the user module at compile time and has no idea what it might contain.

Comment: I still can't find any solution. Anything else trying to dynamically load components seems to use lazy(), but this only seems to work if you make a component part of the application and compile it all together. If you compile a component in a separate module and try to import it to a pre-built application, then it seems like the component has a different context to the application and won't work. It seems like I could almost make it work if JS allowed me to monkey patch the imported module's functions (e.g. replacing mod.useContext() with the application's useContext())...

Comment: @SamBull sorry for long delay I'm in a rush week. I'll have a look back at your issue asap

Comment: If you've got the patience to take 1 more look at this, I've tried to put everything together in a draft PR. Maybe you could take another look and tell me if there's anyway at all to achieve this: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-admin/pull/748

Comment: I've figured out a solution. It's a bit awkward though and won't work with third-party components. Hopefully the solution atleast makes the problem clear. Maybe you have some additional suggestions? https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-admin/pull/767

Comment: I'm afraid I won't have to take a serious look at it anytime soon. Maybe go with the solution that works for you now, I will try to take a look at it after my vacations and see if I can come up with a better solution. If you are seriously in need of help I can try and take another look later but before mid-september (won't quite have free time from that time on). I'll leave a comment on your GH thread, If you can reply to it I'll keep that in mind. Can't promise anything tho. Good luck

Comment: Yep, it's not urgent. Just want to figure out a good longterm solution eventually. I may merge that awkward solution for the medium term, and then add any better solution as an alternative later.